# How to set Action Icon as a button in VF SLDS?

Tags: visualforce, lightning, slds

Is it possible to set an Action Icon to be a button?
In my VF SLDS page, I am returning a list of records. For each record, I am showing an icon. I would like when for a specific record, the icon is clicked, to create a new record.
What I am trying to figure out is how to set the Icon to be clickable.
Here is sample code where I am sowing the Action Icon. The reason I am looking for this to be a button is because I would like to call a method from my controller.

```
<td>
<span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-standard-account" title="Create Account"> 
<svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-icon "> 
<use xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Asset.SLDS, 'assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#account')}"></use>
</svg>
<span class="slds-assistive-text">Create an Account for this record</span>
</span>
</td>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<td>
<button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-brand" title="Create Account">
<svg class="slds-button__icon slds-icon_small" aria-hidden="true">
<use xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Asset.SLDS, 'assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#account')}"></use>
</svg>
<span class="slds-assistive-text">Create Account</span>
 </button>
</td>
```